# DataExporter in Primefaces 12 not exporting Table headers in PDF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-dataexporter

I am using Primefaces 12, and I know that in version 12, the dataExporter has an issue where it does not include the table headers when trying to download the files. [This is the issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9290)

I have written a postprocessor to include them for 'xls' files, but I need help to apply them for 'pdf' files also. I cannot upgrade to primefaces 13 due to some issues.

Comment: What have you tried so far?